# Tensorflow: TypeError: get_variable() got multiple values for keyword argument 'name'

Tags: variables, tensorflow, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, valueerror

I am training the "Show and tell" model using tensorflow in which the model automatically generates the captions of the images. How ever I am getting this error.

This is the traceback:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call 
last)
<ipython-input-14-b6da0a27b701> in <module>()
  1 try:
  2     #train(.001,False,False) #train from scratch
----> 3     train(.001,True,True)    #continue training from pretrained weights @epoch500
  4     #train(.001)  #train from previously saved weights
  5 except KeyboardInterrupt:

<ipython-input-13-39693d0edd0a> in train(learning_rate, continue_training, transfer)
 23     n_words = len(wordtoix)
 24     maxlen = np.max( [x for x in map(lambda x: len(x.split(' ')), captions) ] )
 ---> 25     caption_generator = Caption_Generator(dim_in, dim_hidden, dim_embed, batch_size, maxlen+2, n_words, init_b)
 26 
 27     loss, image, sentence, mask = caption_generator.build_model()

<ipython-input-12-1b31c4175b3a> in __init__(self, dim_in, dim_embed, dim_hidden, batch_size, n_lstm_steps, n_words, init_b)
 11         # declare the variables to be used for our word embeddings
 12         with tf.device("/cpu:0"):
---> 13             self.word_embedding = tf.get_variable(tf.random_uniform([self.n_words, self.dim_embed], -0.1, 0.1), name='word_embedding')
 14 
 15             self.embedding_bias = tf.get_variable(tf.zeros([dim_embed]), name='embedding_bias')
```

**TypeError: get_variable() got multiple values for keyword argument 'name'**

The problem might be that I am passing some extra arguments to the get_variable initializer but I unable to trace it where this problem is occurring.

Here is the code:

```
def get_data(annotation_path, feature_path):
 annotations = pd.read_table(annotation_path, sep='\t', header=None, names=['image', 'caption'])
 return np.load(feature_path,'r'), annotations['caption'].values

def preProBuildWordVocab(sentence_iterator, word_count_threshold=30): # function from Andre Karpathy's NeuralTalk
print('preprocessing %d word vocab' % (word_count_threshold, ))
word_counts = {}
nsents = 0
for sent in sentence_iterator:
  nsents += 1
  for w in sent.lower().split(' '):
    word_counts[w] = word_counts.get(w, 0) + 1
vocab = [w for w in word_counts if word_counts[w] >= word_count_threshold]
print('preprocessed words %d -> %d' % (len(word_counts), len(vocab)))


ixtoword = {}
ixtoword[0] = '.'  
wordtoix = {}
wordtoix['#START#'] = 0 
ix = 1
for w in vocab:
  wordtoix[w] = ix
  ixtoword[ix] = w
  ix += 1

word_counts['.'] = nsents
bias_init_vector = np.array([1.0*word_counts[ixtoword[i]] for i in ixtoword])
bias_init_vector /= np.sum(bias_init_vector) 
bias_init_vector = np.log(bias_init_vector)
bias_init_vector -= np.max(bias_init_vector) 
return wordtoix, ixtoword, bias_init_vector.astype(np.float32)

class Caption_Generator():
def __init__(self, dim_in, dim_embed, dim_hidden, batch_size, n_lstm_steps, n_words, init_b):

    self.dim_in = dim_in
    self.dim_embed = dim_embed
    self.dim_hidden = dim_hidden
    self.batch_size = batch_size
    self.n_lstm_steps = n_lstm_steps
    self.n_words = n_words

    # declare the variables to be used for our word embeddings
    with tf.device("/cpu:0"):
        self.word_embedding = tf.get_variable(tf.random_uniform([self.n_words, self.dim_embed], -0.1, 0.1), name='word_embedding')

        self.embedding_bias = tf.get_variable(tf.zeros([dim_embed]), name='embedding_bias')

    # declare the LSTM itself
        self.lstm = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(dim_hidden)

    # declare the variables to be used to embed the image feature embedding to the word embedding space
        self.img_embedding = tf.get_variable(tf.random_uniform([dim_in, dim_hidden], -0.1, 0.1), name='img_embedding')
        self.img_embedding_bias = tf.get_variable(tf.zeros([dim_hidden]), name='img_embedding_bias')

    # declare the variables to go from an LSTM output to a word encoding output
        self.word_encoding = tf.get_variable(tf.random_uniform([dim_hidden, n_words], -0.1, 0.1), name='word_encoding')
    # initialize this bias variable from the preProBuildWordVocab output
        self.word_encoding_bias = tf.get_variable(init_b, name='word_encoding_bias')

def build_model(self):
    # declaring the placeholders for our extracted image feature vectors, our caption, and our mask
    # (describes how long our caption is with an array of 0/1 values of length `maxlen`  
    img = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [self.batch_size, self.dim_in])
    caption_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [self.batch_size, self.n_lstm_steps])
    mask = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [self.batch_size, self.n_lstm_steps])

    # getting an initial LSTM embedding from our image_imbedding
    image_embedding = tf.matmul(img, self.img_embedding) + self.img_embedding_bias

    # setting initial state of our LSTM
    state = self.lstm.zero_state(self.batch_size, dtype=tf.float32)

    total_loss = 0.0
    with tf.variable_scope("RNN"):
        for i in range(self.n_lstm_steps): 
            if i > 0:
               #if this isn’t the first iteration of our LSTM we need to get the word_embedding corresponding
               # to the (i-1)th word in our caption 
                with tf.device("/cpu:0"):
                    current_embedding = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(self.word_embedding, caption_placeholder[:,i-1]) + self.embedding_bias
            else:
                 #if this is the first iteration of our LSTM we utilize the embedded image as our input 
                current_embedding = image_embedding
            if i > 0: 
                # allows us to reuse the LSTM tensor variable on each iteration
                tf.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables()

                out, state = self.lstm(current_embedding, state)
                    #out, state = self.tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(current_embedding, state)


            if i > 0:
                #get the one-hot representation of the next word in our caption 
                labels = tf.expand_dims(caption_placeholder[:, i], 1)
                ix_range=tf.range(0, self.batch_size, 1)
                ixs = tf.expand_dims(ix_range, 1)
                concat = tf.concat([ixs, labels],1)
                onehot = tf.sparse_to_dense(
                concat, tf.stack([self.batch_size, self.n_words]), 1.0, 0.0)


                #perform a softmax classification to generate the next word in the caption
                logit = tf.matmul(out, self.word_encoding) + self.word_encoding_bias
                xentropy = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logit, labels=onehot)
                xentropy = xentropy * mask[:,i]

                loss = tf.reduce_sum(xentropy)
                total_loss += loss

        total_loss = total_loss / tf.reduce_sum(mask[:,1:])
        return total_loss, img,  caption_placeholder, mask

### Parameters ###
dim_embed = 256
dim_hidden = 256
dim_in = 4096
batch_size = 128
momentum = 0.9
n_epochs = 150

def train(learning_rate=0.001, continue_training=False, transfer=True):

tf.reset_default_graph()

feats, captions = get_data(annotation_path, feature_path)
wordtoix, ixtoword, init_b = preProBuildWordVocab(captions)

np.save('data/ixtoword', ixtoword)

index = (np.arange(len(feats)).astype(int))
np.random.shuffle(index)


sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
n_words = len(wordtoix)
maxlen = np.max( [x for x in map(lambda x: len(x.split(' ')), captions) ] )
caption_generator = Caption_Generator(dim_in, dim_hidden, dim_embed, batch_size, maxlen+2, n_words, init_b)

loss, image, sentence, mask = caption_generator.build_model()

saver = tf.train.Saver(max_to_keep=100)
global_step=tf.Variable(0,trainable=False)
learning_rate = tf.train.exponential_decay(learning_rate, global_step,
                                   int(len(index)/batch_size), 0.95)
train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(loss)
tf.global_variables_initializer().run()

if continue_training:
    if not transfer:
        saver.restore(sess,tf.train.latest_checkpoint(model_path))
    else:
        saver.restore(sess,tf.train.latest_checkpoint(model_path_transfer))
losses=[]
for epoch in range(n_epochs):
    for start, end in zip( range(0, len(index), batch_size), range(batch_size, len(index), batch_size)):

        current_feats = feats[index[start:end]]
        current_captions = captions[index[start:end]]
        current_caption_ind = [x for x in map(lambda cap: [wordtoix[word] for word in cap.lower().split(' ')[:-1] if word in wordtoix], current_captions)]

        current_caption_matrix = sequence.pad_sequences(current_caption_ind, padding='post', maxlen=maxlen+1)
        current_caption_matrix = np.hstack( [np.full( (len(current_caption_matrix),1), 0), current_caption_matrix] )

        current_mask_matrix = np.zeros((current_caption_matrix.shape[0], current_caption_matrix.shape[1]))
        nonzeros = np.array([x for x in map(lambda x: (x != 0).sum()+2, current_caption_matrix )])

        for ind, row in enumerate(current_mask_matrix):
            row[:nonzeros[ind]] = 1

        _, loss_value = sess.run([train_op, loss], feed_dict={
            image: current_feats.astype(np.float32),
            sentence : current_caption_matrix.astype(np.int32),
            mask : current_mask_matrix.astype(np.float32)
            })

        print("Current Cost: ", loss_value, "\t Epoch {}/{}".format(epoch, n_epochs), "\t Iter {}/{}".format(start,len(feats)))
    print("Saving the model from epoch: ", epoch)
    saver.save(sess, os.path.join(model_path, 'model'), global_step=epoch)

try:
#train(.001,False,False) #train from scratch
    train(.001,True,True)    #continue training from pretrained weights @epoch500
#train(.001)  #train from previously saved weights 
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('Exiting Training')
```

Comment: Can you share the stack trace?

Comment: @AlexandrePassos      I've already share the stack trace above

Comment: Does this happen even when you're not restoring your model?

Comment: @AbhishekPatel Yes. The same error even when I am not restoring it

Answer (score 0):

In your constructor, try

```
self.word_embedding = tf.get_variable("word_embedding", initializer=tf.random_uniform([self.n_words, self.dim_embed], -0.1, 0.1))
```

The thing is, the first position argument is `name` and you have the initializer there instead, and then you again define the name, hence the error.

You need to make likewise changes everywhere you use `tf.get_variable`

Comment: No,It doesen't work.It is giving the same error. I've clearly mentioned name = ''word_embedding'' instead of just "word_embedding" so the postioning of the arguments doesen't matter here that is what I think

Comment: @clarky but you have not provided name for the first argument and hence it assumes that is the name. That is why your error says it has multiple name values, I'm sure this works, you might be getting the same error on a different line. Double check please.

Comment: Yes it worked now @Abhishek Patel But now i ran to this error.Do you have any idea about this? TypeError: Using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed. Use `if t is not None:` instead of `if t:` to test if a tensor is defined, and use TensorFlow ops such as tf.cond to execute subgraphs conditioned on the value of a tensor.

Comment: @clarky can you accept the answer if it solved the particular issue, would be helpful to others. As for the bool issue, just do as it says, use the suggested expression and if initially it is supposed to be false, then just set the variable to none. The error itself contains the solution.